# Load text files into database merging duplicates

Tags: mysql, load, duplicates, sum, text-files

I have a MySQL table and large text files with values separated by tabs. This file may contain duplicates. This is an example:

```
foo \t 5
bar \t 42
etc \t 22
bar \t 50
oth \t 12
```

Also, each file may contain duplicates according to the other file. For example:

```
abc \t 33
foo \t 10
```

I want to load these files into the table so that duplicates should be merged (summing the numbers). After importint both files, the database should look like this:

```
| text | num |
+------+-----+
| foo  |  15 |
| bar  |  92 |
| etc  |  22 |
| oth  |  12 |
| abc  |  33 |
```

These are commands I already know:

- Load text file:

  LOAD DATA INFILE "file.txt" INTO TABLE `table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
- Select rows that have duplicates:

  SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `text` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found a way how to achieve this.

Create the main table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`
(`text` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `num` INT(11) NOT NULL);
```

Load file into the table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'local/path/to/file.txt'
INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

Create a temporary table with duplicates summing numbers:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test_tmp`
SELECT `text`,SUM(`num`) FROM `test`
GROUP BY `text` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Delete duplicates from the main table:

```
DELETE FROM `test` WHERE `text`
IN (SELECT `text` FROM `test_tmp`);
```

Copy data into the main table:

```
INSERT INTO `test` SELECT * FROM `test_tmp`;
```

Drop the temporary table:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `test_tmp`;
```

**Is there any better way to do this?**